# Twitter Bootstrap LESS compilation missing styles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

So I have looked at the [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar) component of tb and it has **navbar-inner** class
However when I download [version 3](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v3.0.0) of tb from git hub and manually compile LESS folder those styles are not available in fact lots of styles not available is there is something that I'm missing?

When I compile LESS I compile main file (which is bootstrap.less) that has all the imports.

Would be interesting to know what I'm missing. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 3 dropped the navbar-inner class. The docs you are referencing are from the 2.x branch. See http://getbootstrap.com for the v3 docs, and more specifically http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration for what has changed from the 2.x branch to 3.

Comment: ahh... that's explains then, so I guess if I get LESS for 2.x it should work then.